# How can I read all logs at middleware?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I have about 100 spiders on a server. Every morning all spiders start scraping and writing all of the logs in their logs. Sometimes a couple of them gives me an error. When a spider gives me an error I have to go to the server and read from log file but I want to read the logs from the mail.

I already set dynamic mail sender as follow:

```
class FirstBotSpiderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        return None

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for i in result:
            yield i

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        pass

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for r in start_requests:
            yield r

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
    
    def spider_closed(self, spider,reason):
        error_count = self.stats.get_value('log_count/ERROR')
        counts = self.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count')
        count_403 = self.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/403')
        count_404 = self.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/404')
        robots_404 = self.stats.get_value('robotstxt/response_status_count/404')
        robots_403 = self.stats.get_value('robotstxt/response_status_count/403')
        duplicate_count = self.stats.get_value('item_dropped_count')

        #I want to read all logs here

        content = "some stat string"

        self.mailSender(spider.name,content,logs)

    def mailSender(self,spider,content,logs):
        send_mail(
        "Scrapy "+spider+" done",
        content,
        djsettings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['xxx@xxx.com'],
        )
```

I couldn't figure out how to read the error log at spider_closed on middleware dynamically. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a similar method in my web scraping module.

Below is the implementation you can look at and take reference from.

```
import gzip
import datetime

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy.utils.serialize import ScrapyJSONEncoder

from collections import defaultdict

try:
    from cStringIO import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
 

def format_size(size):
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB']:
        if size < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (size, x)

        size /= 1024.0


class GzipCompressor(gzip.GzipFile):
    extension = '.gz'
    mimetype = 'application/gzip'

    def __init__(self):
        super(GzipCompressor, self).__init__(
            fileobj=PlainCompressor(), mode='w')
        self.read = self.fileobj.read


class PlainCompressor(StringIO):
    extension = ''
    mimetype = 'text/plain'

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.seek(0)

        return StringIO.read(self, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.getvalue())


class StatusMailer(object):
    def __init__(self, recipients, mail, compressor, crawler):
        self.recipients = recipients
        self.mail = mail
        self.encoder = ScrapyJSONEncoder()
        self.files = defaultdict(compressor)

        self.num_items = 0
        self.num_errors = 0
        self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        recipients = crawler.settings.getlist('STATUSMAILER_RECIPIENTS')
        compression = crawler.settings.get('STATUSMAILER_COMPRESSION')

        if not compression:
            compressor = PlainCompressor
        elif compression.lower().startswith('gz'):
            compressor = GzipCompressor
        else:
            raise NotConfigured

        if not recipients:
            raise NotConfigured

        mail = MailSender.from_settings(crawler.settings)
        instance = cls(recipients, mail, compressor, crawler)

        crawler.signals.connect(instance.item_scraped,
                                signal=signals.item_scraped)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_error,
                                signal=signals.spider_error)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_closed,
                                signal=signals.spider_closed)

        return instance

    def item_scraped(self, item, response, spider):
        self.num_items += 1
        self.files[spider.name + '.log'].write(str(self.num_items)+ " " + str(response.url) + '\n')
        self.files[spider.name +
                   '-items.json'].write(self.encoder.encode(item))

    def spider_error(self, failure, response, spider):
        self.files[spider.name + '.log'].write(failure.getTraceback())
        self.num_errors += 1

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        files = []
        for name, compressed in self.files.items():
            files.append((name + compressed.extension,
                          compressed.mimetype, compressed))

        try:
            size = self.files[spider.name + '-items.json'].size
        except KeyError:
            size = 0

        body = '''Crawl statistics:

            - Spider name: {0}
            - Spider started at: {1}
            - Spider finished at: {2}
            - Number of items scraped: {3}
            - Number of errors: {4}
            - Size of scraped items: {5}'''.format(
            spider.name,
            self.start_time,
            datetime.datetime.now(),
            self.num_items,
            self.num_errors,
            format_size(size)
        )

        return self.mail.send(
            to=self.recipients,
            subject='Crawler for %s: %s' % (spider.name, reason),
            body=body,
            attachs=files
        )
```